# Visual Studio: What happened to the "Break when an exception is unhandled" option?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging, exception, visual-studio-2010

As far as I remember, Visual Studio (both 2008 and 2010) used to have an option to break either on thrown exceptions or on unhandled exceptions. Now when I bring up the Exceptions dialog (Ctr+Alt+E), it just offers to break when an exception is thrown:

[image]

I've tried resizing to the columns in that dialog, but that did not help. Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[This](http://vaultofthoughts.net/UserUnhandledCheckboxMissingFromExceptionsWindow.aspx) seems to indicate it can occur if you don't have "Enable Just My Code (Managed Only)" enabled.

Edit: just tried it here (VS 2008) and I can verify that disabling that option will cause the User-Unhandled column to disappear. You can find the option here: Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General

Comment: yup, that was exactly the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have this as well when I've enabled source-server support in VS.NET.
When I have source-server support disabled, then the option to break on unhandled exceptions is still visible.

But, a thought: is it necessary to be able to specify that the IDE should break when an exception is unhandled ?  As far as i know, this is just default behaviour, isn't it ?  So, what's the use to be able to specify that option ?

Comment: Breaking on all exceptions can be quite tedious when working with frameworks that throw exceptions internally (MBUnit and ASP.NET MVC both do). Those exceptions come up every single time I fire up the debugger. Breaking on unhandled exeptions is usually what I really want.