# Debugging drops out at the point of an error (Visual Studio)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, breakpoints, visual-studio-debugging

I've been messing about a bit to try and get my debugger (VS2010) to allow me to step into the framework source code. ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx)) This didn't work and I ran out of time so changed my settings back, and now I don't get dropped into the debugger when a web project (in debug mode) throws an error, I simply get the yellow screen of death.

What's strange is that I can put a breakpoint in my code which works fine, and I can step over my code but as soon as I hit the line causing the error it drops out of the debugger back to the error in the browser.

I'm sure I've just got a setting wrong somewhere but its incredibly frustrating!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague saved me! This article about [Break when exception unhandled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631305/visual-studio-what-happened-to-the-break-when-an-exception-is-unhandled-optio) had the solution, I had the "Enable just my code" unchecked in Tools > Options > Debugging. No idea how it happened, but fixed now!