# UnhandledExceptionEventHandler not catching System.NotImplemented exception

Tags: c#, unhandled-exception

My c# program implements a unhandledExceptionEventHandler. Still, one of the libraries that I use throws up a NotImplemented exception. Windows promptly throws up a dialog box whether I want to continue or exit. How do I catch this exception (so that I can exit without prompting the user?)

Comment: Where's your code? Which library is it? Are you compiled in DEBUG or RELEASE mode? Some more information would be helpful.

Comment: Also whether or not this is WinForms, WPF, or Silverlight.

Comment: The library is bluetooth discovery wrapper from 32feet.codeplex.com. The program was compiled with DEBUG mode. I was performing a neighbor discovery. The exception is thrown from within the library as it asynchronously searches for neighbors.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "c#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: John Saunders, will do in future - thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on VS2010, simply go to the `Debug` menu and hit `Exceptions...`. Now check every exception on `Thrown`. Run your program again from IDE on Debug mode. Now your program will stop on every exception. You will be able to identify what's happenning when you are exiting.

Answer (score 0):

It is more straightforward to wrap your entry points with `try ... catch` than to use the handler, but anyway.  If you are debugging from an IDE, those dialog boxes correspond to the *beginning* of processing of the exception, whereas the `UnhandledExceptionEventHandler` only gets a chance to execute after the stack has been completely unrolled, at the end of the same process, and when there is nothing left on that unfortunate thread for debugging.  You should be able to disable the unwanted dialog in your IDE (for example, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173997/how-to-disable-exception-assistant-and-unhandled-exception-popup-in-visual-studi)).

Comment: This happens when the application was running independently outside the IDE/debugger. In fact, Visual Studio was not even installed on that machine.

Comment: Also, since the library was asynchronously searching searching for neighbors, try ... catch does not catch this exception.

Comment: Nonsense. Something called the code that called the code that threw the exception. Put try/catch around that top-level caller, and it will catch the exception. There's nothing special about `NotImplementedException`.

Comment: @SurendarChandra - I agree with John Saunders.  I don't have much detail on what you did and saw, but the only managed exception that is a little tricky to catch and extinguish is `ThreadAbortException`.

Comment: This is what my code: if (BlueToothRadio.IsSupported) { try {bt = new BluetoothComponent(); bt.DiscoverDevicesComplete += new EventHandler<DiscoverDevicesEventArgs>(discoverComplete); bt.DiscoverDevicesAsync(100, true, true, true, true, null); } catch { if (bt != null) bt.Dispose();} }. My entire program is under a giant try {} catch block too.

Comment: @SurendarChandra Add a surrounding `try` block into `discoverComplete` as well.  It's an asynchronously called handler, so it doesn't help if you protect just the simple act of its adding to the event.

Comment: Yes, discoverComplete is inside a try catch block as well. However, the NotImplementedException happens from IntheHand.Net.Bluetooth.Msft.SocketBlueToothClient.InTheHand.Net.....

Comment: discoverComplete inside the try block?  It should be the other way round...  I suggest you post all the relevant code as part of the question, and also paste the whole stack trace to it.  This way you will make it easiest for everyone to spot the thread on which exceptions are not caught.

Comment: Sorry, meant - everything inside discoverComplete is inside a try ... catch.

Comment: The log is too long for adding as a comment. The exact log is available at http://32feet.codeplex.com/discussions/356073. Hopefully the library maintainers can help with fixing the library. In the meanwhile, it would be great if the application did not throw dialog boxes and just died quietly.